# How can you output a varying argument in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments, output, varying

I am writing a function in Python.

So lets say I have 3 arguments in this function:

```
Function (arg1, arg2, arg3)
  arg1 = arg2 * arg3
```

When the function is called, it is as such:

```
function(arg1=var1, arg2=var2, arg3=var3)
```

Now the thing is, these variables, (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`) vary in the case of this function being called. So they could be `var4`, `var5`, `var6`, etc.

Given that these variables vary, what would be the syntax to make this function change a varying argument?

ie. `arg1 = arg2 * arg3` changes `arg1`. Because `arg1 = var1`.

What I need is somehow for `arg1` to stand in as an actual proxy to `var1` so that not only is `arg1` changed but `var1` is changed also.

This is evidently not doable with simply with `arg1=var1`

I assume this could also be done with other function commands or structure. How does not really concern me I just need to output a change into a varying argument.

***Edit***
 This function is specifically designed to take an argument called, not necessarily knowing what it is, and then inside of the function, that argument which is converted into a formula variable such as x in y = mx + b, needs to be converted back into its variable target, all inside of the function.

The problem here is that I don't know how to target the original variable.

So if it were function(a=cats, b=dogs, c=mice)

a = c/2 - b*2

how do I then set cat=a when cat is variable?

I can't just say cat=a because maybe the input is 
function(a=bird, b=flys, c=cats)

Comment: That depends entirely on the language, but what you are asking for is usually called a reference (You want two or more variables to refer to the same data in memory).

Comment: Yeah, sorry its in python, I edited the title and post.

Comment: Could you be more specific, paul, as to the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def f(x, y):
    return x*y

a, b = 1, 2

c = f(a, b)
```

Instead of having your function try to alter its arguments directly, return any results the function produces. This turns out to be a much cleaner, more useful way to structure your code. For example, you can do

```
print f(1, f(2, 3))
```

instead of having to create temporary variables:

```
f(a, 2, 3)
f(b, 1, a)
print b
```

Instead of doing

```
f(arg1=var1, arg2=var2, arg3=var3)
f(arg1=var4, arg2=var5, arg3=var6)
```

do the following:

```
var1 = f(var2, var3)
var4 = f(var5, var6)
```

Comment: If I return the results out, how can I target the var1 if its variable?

Comment: @NickSimas: See expanded answer.

Comment: Ok that works yeah, but its more like
var1 = f(a=var1, b=var2, c=var3)
  a=b+c
  return a

Comment: I need the temporary variables because all of the arguments are variable.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong though, cause I'm trying to make this formula as clean as possible.

Comment: I don't think the arguments "being variable" has the implications you think it does. A function called with different arguments over the course of a program doesn't need to be written any different from a function only called in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not doable with `arg1=var1`, it's because of this:

> Python passes references-to-objects by value (like Java), and
>   everything in Python is an object. This sounds simple, but then you
>   will notice that some data types seem to exhibit pass-by-value
>   characteristics, while others seem to act like pass-by-reference...
>   what's the deal?
>
> It is important to understand mutable and immutable objects. Some
>   objects, like strings, tuples, and numbers, are immutable. Altering
>   them inside a function/method will create a new instance and the
>   original instance outside the function/method is not changed. Other
>   objects, like lists and dictionaries are mutable, which means you can
>   change the object in-place. Therefore, altering an object inside a
>   function/method will also change the original object outside.

Why not just return `arg1` and set `val1` to it?

Comment: I can't set var1 because it's variable.

Comment: Somehow in your code you are calling the function, be it inside a loop that iterates over things you use as parameters or whatever. Wherever you do that, you know what parameters you are calling the function with. Right after calling the function, set the parameter to the result of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a specific syntax regarding references (not that I know of at least). If you want your argument to be passed *as reference* to a function, it has to be mutable (eg. list, dictionary).

```py
def foobar(a, b):
    a[0] = 42   # This will modify the list
    b[0] = '-'  # This will modify the value of b passed to the function

foobar(
    [4,8,15,16,23,42],  # This argument is passed by reference, mutable
    'asdf'              # This one is passed by value, immutable
)
```

Comment: I see what you mean but could you be more specific as to the syntax for changing the var1 inside of the function?